# Finding a contradiction for inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, real-numbers

Assuming that $a_1 \leq b_1\leq c_1 \leq d_1 \le n_1$ and $a_2 \leq b_2\leq c_2 \leq d_2 \le n_2$ and $(a_1 + a_2) < (b_1 + b_2) < (c_1 + c_2) < (d_1+d_2)$ (and all the numbers are natural and positive) can we find a contradiction in the following four inequalities:

$n_2 a_1 \ge a_2 (n_1-1)$,$n_2 b_1 \ge b_2 (n_1-1)$, $ (n_2-1) c_1 \le c_2 (n_1)$ and $d_1 n_2 \ge d_2(n_1-1)$?

If yes, could you please give a hint about how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Works e.g. with $a_1=2$, $a_2=1$, $b_1=3$, $b_2=1$, $c_1=3$, $c_2=10000$.

Comment: Thank you, could you please see and edit? Is there a contradiction now?

Comment: @MariyaKav you are forming a similar bad habit to one I have, it's not fair to people volunteering their help and knowledge to make incremental edits in response to counter arguments they present, take some time before posting and restrict yourself to asking only one question per day in total